# Compensation for baggage delay (China Eastern, international flight)

Tags: luggage, compensation

I flew from Japan to Singapore. Between there was a transit in Shanghai, where my check-in bag somehow got lost.

But eventually, 6 days and 10 hours after I got to Singapore, the bag was delivered to my address in Singapore (after many phone calls).

What compensation can I get from China Eastern?

Edit: Google reveals that some guy managed to get half his flight money back (through a Chinese court) after his baggage got delayed for a month and a half:

> China Eastern Airlines Ordered to Pay over Delayed Luggage
>
> By Xu Fang, Shanghai Daily | Feb. 12, 2009
>
> China Eastern Airlines has been ordered to refund half the cost of a round-trip ticket to a passenger whose luggage was delayed for one and a half months.
>
> The Changning District People's Court also ruled that the airline to pay compensation of about 1,000 yuan (US$146) for the loss of property from his luggage.
>
> The passenger, a businessman surnamed Tang, booked a round-trip between Paris and Shanghai from China Eastern last July in Paris. The ticket price was EUR813.77 (US$1,053.62).
>
> On September 7, he arrived at Shanghai Pudong International Airport on schedule. But his luggage didn't. Tang reported the loss before leaving the airport.
>
> He didn't get any news about the missing luggage before he was due to return on September 22. During that period he had asked several times for a refund on his return ticket.
>
> Tang said the loss of his luggage prevented him from completing his business in Shanghai and he couldn't return to Paris as scheduled.
>
> The airline finally found Tang's luggage in late October. But a mobile phone was missing and some food had rotted, the court heard.
>
> The airline offered 1,000 yuan in compensation. Tang then sued China Eastern for a refund of the return ticket and 2,000 yuan for his loss.
>
> The court ruled that the airline was guilty of a serious breach of contract as it had failed to find Tang's luggage before the return date on the ticket.
>
> Tang's request for a refund was reasonable, it said. ([Source](http://www.wcarn.com/cache/news/9/9958.html))

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there are no regulations regarding delayed baggage compensation and China Eastern's T&Cs do not cover anything other than damage or loss.

If the delay forced you to buy clothes, then they may reimburse those costs, but your post sounds like it was your return flight home, so this would not likely qualify.

Your best bet is to write a polite letter explaining the delayed baggage and its inconvenience to you, and ask what they can do for you.  But realistically at best you may get a small credit towards a future flight or frequent flyer points if you are a member of their FF program.